# copy all duplicate elements from the corresponding row in array A to a new two-dimensional array B

Tags: c++

I have a two-dimensional array called A which is filled randomly. My task is to copy all duplicate elements from the corresponding row to a new two-dimensional array B. Some example pf correct work:

```
5 7 6 4 6 2
1 9 5 1 5 7
7 8 9 8 9 7   //input

6
1 5
7 8 9   //output
```

So I wrote a code for this task but it works absolutely wrong and incomprehensible to me.
There is my code:

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
  typedef char _TCHAR;
  #define _tmain main
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 3 + rand() % 6,
    m = 3 + rand() % 6,// randoming size of 'a' array
    count = 0;

    bool toAdd = true;
    int a[n][m];
    int **b = new int* [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       b[i] = new int[m];//creating dynamic two-dimensional 'b' array
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
         a[i][k] = -15 + rand() % 30; //randomly filling the 'a' array
         cout << a[i][k] << " "; //showing an 'a' array
      }
      cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
         count = 0;
         for (int f = 1; f < n - i; f++) {
            if (a[i][k] == a[i+f][k]) { //checking if current element is equal to any further element of the same row
               toAdd = true;
               for (int c = 0; c < count; c++) {
                  if (a[i][k] == b[c][k]) {//checking if there is such a number in 'b' array already
                    toAdd = false;
                  }
               }
               if (toAdd) {
                  b[count][k] = a[i][k];
                  count++;
               }
            }
         }
      }
    }

    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < m; k++) {
         cout << b[i][k] << " ";//showing new 'b' array
      }
      cout << endl;
    }

    delete [] b;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

But the result of compiling is not what I want to have.

[image: result of code]

Is there any ideas where is a mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Minor point, "*result of compiling*" should be "*result of running*".

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: better dont use random input for testing and debugging. While testing and debugging you want reproducability.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  And I agree with @idclev463035818 -- get rid of the `rand()` stuff and use the input you posted in the question.

Comment: actually `rand` alone wouldnt be that bad, but `srand(time(NULL));` makes sensible testing almost impossible

Comment: Also this  `int a[n][m];` is not valid C++.  If you were going to use this invalid code, then why didn't you use this syntax to create the `b` array?   In any event, the code is not valid C++, as arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by compile-time expressions, not a runtime variable.  Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(m)); std::vector<std::vector<int>> b = a;`, and the problem becomes a lot easier to solve.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion between row and column indices. Here, `if (a[i][k] == a[i+f][k]) `, I would have expected something like `if (a[i][k] == a[i][k+f]) `

Comment: @Damien oh yea, I totally messed up with all this indexes, thanks for the help :)